# Active Directory Server for Windows Clustering

Tags: active-directory, windows-cluster

I understand that Windows clustering requires Active Directory. 
If I were to setup a Windows Server 2008 R2 cluster, will there be any issues if the Active Directory server is running Windows Server 2003 and not Windows Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there would not be a problem with this. The AD requirement is there so that the hosts in your cluster have a single authentication domain, allowing them to correctly interact with each other. The AD version/mode can be higher or lower than the cluster members.

Comment: Okay, if the AD server is down, then the cluster failover will not function ?

Comment: Correct, if AD goes down the cluster will eventually fail as well.  This is why you must always have two AD servers.  Upvoted the answer.